# Class Loader order not able to change

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, rational-rsa

I am using IBM RSA 7.5 and Websphere Server 6.1 as a application server.
I am not able to change Class Loader Order dropdown box. It has disable state. 
How to enable that. I need to change the item "Classes Loaded with parent class loader first" to "Classes Loaded with application class loader first".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The classloader options are disabled in the admininstrative console because the application was published in a "loose configuration" manner. What this means is that your application binaries and descriptor files do not reside in the WAS application repository. Since you published them via RAD (which is most likely configured to 'Run with resources in the workspace') then the application binaries exist in the output folders of your various projects and WAS is instructed to read the binaries/descriptor files from that location. As a result, the WAS admin console is not able to make changes to these files so the functionality is disabled.

Here is a document which describes how to can accomplish the task you want when using this publishing mechanism via RAD:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.enhanced.ear.doc/topics/tapplicationsv6.html

Using this manner to change the classloader settings results in this information being stored with the application (in the EAR project) so you will no longer need to change it when the application is published to any WAS runtime (i.e. in development or production)."

[From the IBM developer help website](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014584202#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014584371)

Comment: Thanks!  This saved me significant frustration and aggravation.  Am using WAS 8.5, but the info remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this one a lot, and even bumped on your question being desperate.

Although i had a different setup,publishing my application from Eclipse, unchecking "Minimize application files copied to the server" in eclipse server config solved the issue for me.